# Mass-energy of black hole spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, angular-momentum

[This](https://medium.com/amazing-science/rotating-black-holes-the-most-powerful-energy-generators-in-the-universe-832439add442) article describes a paper in which the spin of the supermassive black-hole in M87 was observed and its corresponding energy was calculated.

The figure given was 10^64 ergs of energy contained within the spin of the black-hole. By mass-energy equivalence, this corresponds to 1.1*10^40 kg. That would mean 5.55 billion suns' worth of mass-energy are contained within the rotational energy of the black hole.

I find this extraordinary given the black hole weighs 6.5 billion suns, only slightly (proportionally) larger than the energy contained in its spin.

So, if an advanced civilisation were to extract all this rotational energy, would we be left with a black hole weighing only one billion suns, or are these entirely separate components? If the former, how does extracting a black-hole's mass-energy through its spin comply with the conservation of information? Does the black-hole spin somehow encode a large amount of information about its components?

Finally, if large proportions of the mass-energy of black-holes can be stored in their spin, is there an upper limit? For example could you have a spin-black-hole where 100% of its mass-energy is stored in its spin?

Thanks

Comment: *The figure given was 10^64 ergs of energy contained within the spin of the black-hole. By E=mc^2, this corresponds to 1.1*10^40 Joules.* You don’t use $E=mc^2$ to convert from ergs to joules.

Comment: Sorry I meant kg. Ergs to joules is 1e-7 conversion factor so 1e57 Joules. We can then use E / (300,000,000^2) = m to get 1.1*10^40 kg. A solar mass is ~ 2e30 kg, so that is then 5.55 billion solar masses

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process): “the theoretical maximum energy that can be extracted from an uncharged [rotating] black hole is 29% of its original mass”

Comment: Is that the theoretical maximum that can be extracted using the penrose process? Or the theoretical maximum proportion of mass-energy stored in the spin?

Comment: I’m not sure. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah various sources collate that 29% is the maximum mass-energy stored in the spin. I'm not sure why these measurements and calculations suggest much more